# Making regex less inclusive

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all

I have a regex I'm trying to get out of a string. It seems to be including way too much. Here's my code.

```
preg_match_all('/<li class="has-activity"><a class="group-entity" 
href="(.*?)"><span class="activity-count">(.*)<\/span><span 
class="image"><img alt="(.*?)" src/i',$output,$matches);
```

I JUST want it to grab the stuff as seen in (.*?) , but it seems to want to grab more.

MORE INFO:

Here's an example of what I'm trying to extract from. This is just one entity though. (Using preg_match_all)

```
<li class="has-activity"><a class="group-entity" href="/grp/home?gid=2813868&amp;trk=my_groups-tile-grp">
<span class="activity-count">7</span>
<span class="image"><img alt="[Rated #1 in Marketing] The Social Media Marketing Group" src
```

The two main things I need to grab is the group href ("/grp/home?gid=2813868&trk=my_groups-tile-grp" in this instance) and the group name (the thing between the alt tag. "[Rated #1 in Marketing] The Social Media Marketing Group" in this case)

With my updated code of (.?*), it seems to be grabbing the NAME just fine. But I can't properly grab the href of the group.

Comment: give some examples please of text and what you need to extract and how it fails?

Comment: Don't use regex to parse html, just don't. It will never work and will have an infinite number of problems. Instead try php domdocument

Comment: If you want `(.*)` to act as `(.*?)` why not use `(.*?)`? A parser would be far more reliable. Without seeing what you are running this on it is hard to say why it is failing.

Comment: Yeah. I tried to use (.*?) and it's still not working. When using (.*?) , it grabs <img alt="(.*?)" correctly, but not the href of group-entity.

Comment: please specify along with the sample xml what you need to extract

Comment: you might have a problem with *greediness* (the default mode for regex)

Comment: You are searching for `<li class="has-activity"><a class="group-entity" 
href="(.*?)">` there is no new line between the `class` attribute and the `href`. Same with the span. https://regex101.com/r/tX8aT2/1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For starters since `.*` seem to match attributes they can be replaced with `[^"]*`

i.e

```
preg_match_all('/<li class="has-activity"><a class="group-entity" 
href="([^"]*)"><span class="activity-count">(.*)<\/span><span 
class="image"><img alt="([^"]*)"/i',$output,$matches);
```

if inside `span` there are no more tags, just text you can also use

```
preg_match_all('/<li class="has-activity"><a class="group-entity" 
href="([^"]*)"><span class="activity-count">([^<]*)<\/span><span 
class="image"><img alt="([^"]*)"/i',$output,$matches);
```

this is exact and will not match more nor override elements and attributes, although (general) `xml/html` parsing is not easy using just regular expressions

**update**

html sample code

```
<li class="has-activity"><a class="group-entity" href="/grp/home?gid=2813868&amp;trk=my_groups-tile-grp"><span class="activity-count">6</span><span class="image"><img alt="[Rated #1 in Marketing] The Social Media Marketing Group" src
```

`<a class="group-entity" href="LINK"` and the `alt` of that `img` tag need to be extracted

use following

```
preg_match_all('/<li.*?class="has-activity".*?href="([^"]*)".*?<img.*?alt="([^"]*)"/i',$output,$matches);
```

try not to use `preg_match_all` and if neded add the [`multiline` flag (i.e `'/../m'`)](http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php) plus if more refined matching is needed use an xml parser (as suggested)

Comment: That doesn't work at all.

Comment: can you give some examples please of text and what is expected to match? i already made this comment above, to see how it fails

Comment: So here's an example of a thing I'm trying to grab from.

    <li class="has-activity"><a class="group-entity" href="/grp/home?gid=2813868&amp;trk=my_groups-tile-grp"><span class="activity-count">6</span><span class="image"><img alt="[Rated #1 in Marketing] The Social Media Marketing Group" src





The span class of activity-account always varys, but I don't care to grab it. 

I just want to get <a class="group-entity" href="LINK" 

and the alt of that img tag.

Comment: Update your question with the code sample.

Comment: and you need to extract what exactly?

Comment: @user1687621, ok updating my answer with xml sample and extraction

Comment: Updated explanation in my question.

Comment: @user1687621 updated my answer

Answer (score 1):

```
preg_match_all('<li class="has\-activity"><a class="group\-entity" href=(.*?)"><span class="activity\-count">([0-9]+)<\/span><span class="image"><img alt="(.*)" src/i',$output,$matches);
```

Regex isn't the best tool for extracting html. It can get very messy. I find jQuery extremely useful for extracting html content, and then if I need to, I can perform string operations on it in PHP afterwards.

The reason why regular expressions are so tricky with html is edge cases. A slight change to the html could break the entire regular expression.